# Ubuntu 16.04 installation using serial console - unreadable characters

Tags: boot, system-installation, 16.04, console, serial-port

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an appliance that does not have ports for a display (i.e. VGA, HDMI, DVI). I have made a bootable USB stick using the Ubuntu ISO using Unetbootin and edited three files (syslinux.cfg, text.cfg, isolinux.cfg) using the description found here: https://github.com/ynkjm/ubuntu-serial-install

After all the initial text while booting it bring me to a menu, this menu however is unreadable.

┌───────────────────────┤ [!!] S␊┌␊ ▒ ┌▒┼±┤▒±␊ ├────────────────────────┐
  │                                                                         │
  │ C␤⎺⎺⎽␊ ├␤␊ ┌▒┼±┤▒±␊ ├⎺ ␉␊ ┤⎽␊␍ °⎺⎼ ├␤␊ ␋┼⎽├▒┌┌▒├␋⎺┼ ⎻⎼⎺␌␊⎽⎽ T␤␊        │
  │ ⎽␊┌␊␌├␊␍ ┌▒┼±┤▒±␊ ┬␋┌┌ ▒┌⎽⎺ ␉␊ ├␤␊ ␍␊°▒├ ┌▒┼±┤▒±␊ °⎺⎼ ├␤␊ ␋┼⎽├▒┌┌␊␍   │
  │ ⎽≤⎽├␊└.                                                                 │;3H│                                                │

│ L▒┼±┤▒±␊:                                                               │
  │                                                                         │
                                 C                                         │
  │                               E┼±┌␋⎽␤                                   │6;3H│                                               │

│                                                                │
  │                                                                         │

└⎺┴␊⎽;  ⎽␊┌␊␌├⎽;

Is there anyone who knows what's wrong and how it can be solved?

Hans

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using minicom. See, http://pbxbook.com/other/mac-tty.html#minicom

I had the same issue installing ubuntu on my pandaboard ES. I was not able to get the mac terminal nor screen to talk to the ncurses installer.

I'd love a solution that does not require me to install more software on my mac. But for now minicom works.

Answer (score 0):

Minicom fixed it for me as well.

For me another workaround was to disconnect the usb/serial adapter, restart `screen`, and hit Control-l to force a redraw on each and every dialog window (this is quite labour intensive and time consuming obviously).